# Is there a term for "square-summable almost surely"?

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

Is there a term for a sequence of random variables with the following property:

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^\infty X_i^2 \right] < \infty$$

The current language I'm using is that $X$ is square-summable almost surely, but really that should mean this:

$$P\left(\sum_{i = 1}^\infty X_i^2 < \infty \right) = 1$$

which is a slightly weaker claim. There are so many terms for forms of convergence weaker than almost sure convergence--where are all the terms for stronger forms?

Comment: $L^2$ summable?

Comment: I thank that would get confused with convergence in L^2

Comment: Observe that $E(\sum X_i^2) = \sum E(X_i^2)$ (by Tonelli's theorem), hence you actually have a series in $\mathscr{L}^2.$ Simply say that the series converges in $\mathscr{L}^2.$